# Workflow 4 defining a Property in the Argument Tab

Tags: .net, workflow-foundation-4

In workflow 4, I created an Activity and in the argument tab, I added an argument where the direction is Property (not in, out or inout).

Now I then added a IF activity, I can't seem to access the value of the Property in the Condition Expression of the IF activity?

Is there a way to access value of the a Property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make your argument in an InArgument or an InOutArgument to be able to use it in an expression.

Comment: So is it preferable to always you InArgument instead of Property since most of MS activity uses expressions?